# Material is not correctly applied to geometry node primitives other than ico sphere

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am trying to apply a material to a cube created through a geometry node mesh primitive.

The material only looks correct on meshes created without the use of the geometry editor and ico sphere nodes.

On every other type of mesh primitive node (UV sphere, cone, cylinder, etc) the material looks incorrect.

I have not had any luck using the Set Material node.

How do I apply the material correctly?

Material:
https://polyhaven.com/a/sandstone_cracks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

just use this setup here:

[image]

so unplug your texture coordinate and use uv_map.

Comment: Had the same question, and this was it! Thank you! :'D

Comment: you are welcome